# Problem with JasperSoft and dataset JSONQL

Tags: json, jasper-reports

I'm not an expert on soft jasper, so I think my problem is something trivial that I'm missing. I'm trying to create a DataSet using a JSONQL query, but my dataset remains empty. I create a list with this JRDataSource expression:

```
((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("prestazioni_a_confronto.verifica(tipologia == 'M')")
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
{
    "id": 22399,
    "prestazioni": [
        {
            "quantita": 10.000,
            "verifica": {
                "codice": "5M88A",
                "tipologia": "M",
                "descrizione": "mag.30% fascia prodottiva a (forfettaria annue)"
            },
            "unita_misura": "Numero"
        }
    ],    
    "data_sopralluogo": "07/10/2022",
    "controllore_principale": {
        "cognome": "sys",
        "nominativo": "admin"
    },
    "prestazioni_a_confronto": [
        {
            "quantita": 10.000,
            "verifica": {
                "codice": "A560",
                "tipologia": "M",
                "descrizione": "BOVINI ADULTI  (di eta' uguale o superiore a 8 mesi)"
            },
            "fuori_fascia": false,
            "unita_misura": "Capi"
        },
        {
            "quantita": 1.000,
            "verifica": {
                "codice": "A562",
                "tipologia": "M",
                "descrizione": "SOLIPEDI/EQUIDI"
            },
            "fuori_fascia": false,
            "unita_misura": "Capi"
        }
    ]    
}
```

```
<subDataset name="Prestazioni_M_DataSet" uuid="7284671c-397a-4e70-8ba6-cae72e73fe51">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="RicevutaPrestazioni_DataAdapter.jrdax"/>
        <queryString language="jsonql">
            <![CDATA[prestazioni_a_confronto.verifica(tipologia == "M")]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="codice" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="codice"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[codice]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you have a mix of `json` and `jsonql` languages in your report.
Please make sure that you have:

- your main query language(the one after the `<subDataset />` element) set to `jsonql`, something like:

  ```
   <queryString language="jsonql">
       <![CDATA[]]>
   </queryString>
  ```
- your list's `dataSourceExpression` is based on `JsonQLDataSource` and uses double quotes instead of single quotes, like this:

  ```
   <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonQLDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("prestazioni_a_confronto.verifica(tipologia == \"M\")")]]></dataSourceExpression>
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I modified my dataSourceExpression as you told me but I get an error like this: `
[....]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource cannot be cast to class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonQLDataSource (net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource and net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonQLDataSource are in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @1f71e024) 
`

Comment: This means you are still mixing json with jsonql. Did you check my first point?

Comment: Yes I change all reference from json to jsonql directly in my jrxml file. I can't paste all here couse it's too long. But this is my subDataset part: `<subDataset name="Prestazioni_M_DataSet" uuid="7284671c-397a-4e70-8ba6-cae72e73fe51">
  <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="RicevutaPrestazioni_DataAdapter.jrdax"/>
  <queryString language="jsonql">
   <![CDATA[prestazioni_a_confronto.verifica(tipologia == "M")]]>
  </queryString> 
 </subDataset>`

Comment: I suspect it's something about the java compiler version...is it possible?

Comment: It doesn't look like a java version related issue, it's more about configuration. I think it's better if you could post a complete `.jrxml` and the data adapter files.